# Restore-SPSite to different managed path Site Collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, backup, restore

I have a backup taken with below code from SharePoint 2013 site URL: `http://sharepoint/sites/test/`

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity http://sharepoint/sites/test/ -Path C:\Backup\BackupTest.bak
```

Now If I want to restore this backup to the site collection with `Explicit Inclusion` which is `http://sharepoint/test`

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://sharepoint/test -Path C:\Backup\BackupTest.bak
```

Will this scenario work for restoring the site with above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long backup is from same version of SharePoint (i tjink you are moving within same farm) and healthy backup(Not corrupted) then it will work.

We restored the sites between farm / web apps using same method, never had issie.

Comment: Yes the version is the same. Just different site collection. Currently I don't have permission to check the same that's why I posted this question if someone had the same situation.

Comment: i am sure, you will be ok. it is common day to day operation.